# rename file from /tmp dir to another destination

Tags: php

I try to move a temporary file located in the `/tmp` dir to another dir somewhere else on the server using the `rename()` function. But I get an error:

> Permission denied (Code: 2)

for the temporary file. How can I move a temporary file to another location? If I check that the file exists with `file_exists()` I get true. And if I `copy()` the temporary file it works fine.

Here's my code so far:

```
 $toPath = '/var/www/htdocs/myproject/some/file.pdf'

 $fileName = 'myfile.pdf';
 $filePath = sys_get_temp_dir() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName;

 rename($filePath, $toPath); // Permission denied (Code: 2) here
```

Comment: Well, do you have the correct permissions? Don't forget, `copy()` only needs read permissions, to read the file and write it elsewhere. Whereas `rename()` requires permissions to move the file.

Comment: Check what is actually returned by sys_get_temp_dir() - as per the docs, it may or may not have a trailing '/'

Comment: @TonyWilk It does have a trailing slash. The file is also readable. I just wonder why PHP can **create** the file bit than not **rename** it...

Comment: So.. is your $filepath ACTUALLY: "temp_dir//$filename"  (assuming DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR == '/') ?

Comment: The path I get is `/tmp/myfile.pdf` so everything seems to be okay with that. I can eben `unlink()` the temporary file but not use `rename()`.

Comment: Ok, as suggested earlier by 'Ben', it must be permissions and/or destination dir/file

Comment: That's clear. But why can I create, unlink, copy the file but not rename it?

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER I had the same issue, and someone gave a useful tip on another thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25076006/php-move-with-rename-fails-but-combination-of-copy-and-unlink-works#comment39014262_25076006
For me, it was "Invalid cross-device link" because the destination file was on a Windows Share.
I ended up copying and then unlinking the file in my PHP code.

Answer (score 1):

this is caused by sticky bit set on the directory:

drwxrwxrwt. 8 root root 4096 Feb 6 09:38 .

sticky bit basically stops non-owners of file to rename or delete the file. It is usually set on /tmp and similar directories where multiple users have write permissions and/or save temporary files in, in order to prevent accidental deletion.

For more info, see: https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/02/sticky-bit/