# PHP: move with rename fails, but combination of copy and unlink works

Tags: php, rename, file-move

I am trying to use PHP's `rename` to move a file to a different folder (and also rename the file in the same step). However, `rename` always returns `false`. On the other hand, using a combination of `copy` and `unlink` works just fine. What could be causing this?

The relevant code looks like this:

```
  if (!rename($targetpath, $backuppath)) {
    // if rename fails, try with copy and delete
    if (!copy($targetpath, $backuppath)) 
      die("9\nCould not move existing file to backup");
    touch($backuppath, filemtime($targetpath));
    if (!unlink($targetpath))
      die("9\nCould not move existing file to backup");
  }
```

The paths would be e.g.

```
$targetpath: /path/to/plots/some.pdf
$backuppath: /path/to/plots/old/some.pdfX14068815860
```

Comment: PHP version is 5.1.6.

Comment: Is it on Windows ? Seems like `rename` won't work on windows systems if the destination path / file already exists.

Comment: No, it's Apache/2.2.3 on Scientific Linux.

Comment: There have been a number of bug fixes for `rename()` in the past: http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php. Can you reproduce the same problem on a newer PHP version? Is there anything special about your files, e.g. they're symlinks? FWIW: 5.1 on Windows...?! [*shudder*](http://php.net/eol.php) ;)

Comment: Most likely a permission error.. please look through the strace for the exact error code rename is giving: `strace php script.php 2>&1 | grep '^rename'` That will give you the exact error code, cross check it with `man 2 rename` to know more.

Answer (score 0):

Start by checking out whet the error was:

```
print_r(error_get_last());
```

What version of php are you using? On older versions, `rename` only works if both source and destination are on the same filesystem. On some systems, `rename` will also fail if you have an open file descriptor for that file.

Comment: Unfortunately, `error_get_last()` was introduced only with 5.2.0.

Comment: Both source and destination are on the same filesystem (`stat` gives the same hex string under "Device").